# Typescript polymorphic behaviour

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to assign proper types in the following code so that TS becomes happy?

```
function getRowCells<T extends string | string[]>(rowLabels: T[]): T[] {
   return [1, 2, 3]
     .map((item, i) => {
       const labels = rowLabels[i];
       if (typeof labels === 'string') {
         return labels + item;
       }
       return getRowCells(labels);           // error here, see the description below
     });
}
```

The error highlights `labels` identifier with the following error:

Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.

Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2345)

The idea is to be able to pass smth like `['label', ['two', 'three']]` and receive `['label1', ['two1', 'three2']]`.

If we omit the types this snippet becomes a correct JS code, so I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the same result in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive type, like in example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050).

Problem with your attempt to solve the problem is that output of the `getRowCells` function is not just `string | string[]` but could be also `string | string[] | (string[])[]`, etc... basically recursive structure.

```js
type ValueOrArray<T> = T | Array<ValueOrArray<T>>;

function getRowCells(rowLabels: ValueOrArray<string>[]): ValueOrArray<string>[] {
   return [1, 2, 3]
     .map((item, i) => {
       const labels = rowLabels[i];
       if (typeof labels === 'string') {
         return labels + item;
       }
       return getRowCells(labels);           // no error here
     });
}
```

Alternative approach could be function overloads, where you "tell" to typescript compiler specific output for `string[]` input:

```js
function getRowCells(rowLabels: string[]): string[]
function getRowCells(rowLabels: (string | string[])[]):(string | string[])[] {
   return [1, 2, 3]
     .map((item, i) => {
       const labels = rowLabels[i];
       if (typeof labels === 'string') {
         return labels + item;
       }
       return getRowCells(labels);           // no error here either
     });
}
```

Comment: Your solution is great, thank you! However, I already had tried to overload the function with `rowLabels: string[]` and `rowLabels: string[][]` with no luck, can you explain why?

Comment: Thanks. If I understood your description well, issue is that main/implementation method input parameters have to be union of all possible overloads. So implementation has to have `rowLabels` defined in a such way that it's accepting both `string[]` and `string[][]`, to accommodate both overloads. It's kind of catch-all case.